# Modularing Shiny - Pop-up box

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny-app I use pop-up boxes to allow the user to quickly look up data in a table. That works well using `showModal`, however currently I'm creating some module servers and there I run into issues. What I understood, is that the `id` in a module ui needs to be defined using `ns` (as is done below for the action button).
However, my data table inside the pop-up box is defined inside the moduleServer. If I use `ns("my_database")` there, I get the message that `ns` is not a recognized function.

How can I get that table to show inside my pop-up box, embedded in a moduleServer?

```
library(shiny)

dataPage <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    column(12,
        h1("Testing my database pop up"),
        actionButton(ns("show_database"), "Show my database")
    )
  )
}

dataServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      observeEvent(input$show_database, { # Pop-up box, currently for testing purposes
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "My database",
          "My database",
          dataTableOutput("my_database"),
          easyClose = TRUE,
          footer = NULL
        ))
      })

      output$my_database <- renderDataTable({
        temp <- data.frame(a = seq(1,10), b = letters[1:10])
        temp
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataPage("data1", "Counter #1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataServer("data1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can use `sessions$ns`.  See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/session.html) for details.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you wanna turn that into an answer?